# Flash Registration Form

Tags: php, mysql, flash, forms, registration

I need help with my flash registration form. I made sure all my information is correct, but when I enter the information, it doesn't seem to enter it into the mysql database. Here is the flash code:

```
var lvSend:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var lvReceive:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

register_btn.onRelease = function() {
var valid:Boolean = validateForm();

if(valid){
//gather information and put in loadvars object
lvSend.username = username.tInput.text;
lvSend.password = password.tInput.text;
lvSend.email = email.tInput.text;

//send information php script for insertion into database
lvSend.sendAndLoad("register.php", "POST");
}
};
function validateForm():Boolean{
if(username.tInput.text == "" || password.tInput.text == "" || email.tInput.text == ""){
    return false;       
}
    return true;
}
function clearTextFields():Void{
username.tInput.text = "";
password.tInput.text = "";
email.tInput.text = "";
}
```

Here is the Php Code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvvcO.png

Sorry that my code is in picture form. That was the best way I could make it readable by you guys.My problem is that all the information in both codes seem correct. All my text fields are called username, password, and email, same goes for the database columns. The database info isn't wrong because I used the php code with html, I just can't get it to work with flash. My php file is called register.php and my flash file is called play.swf. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
lvReceive.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
if (success) {
    trace("ok");
}
else {
    trace("error");
    }

lvSend.sendAndLoad("register.php", lvReceive, "POST");
```

Comment: @user1404017 Also, dont forget to format the response from PHP as parameters: `message=some text&status=ok&anotherVar=anotherValue`and so on like a querystring. This way you can grab its values as `lvReceive.paramName`.

Comment: @rcdmk I don't fully understand what your saying? Can you give me an example by using my code?

Comment: Oh btw I just noticed a huge error in my php file. The vars I set for my database info at the top isn't the same as the ones I used for mysql_connect.

Comment: I changed the top vars but it still doesn't work. I put the code in a syntax checker and it said Parse error: Unexpected T_VARIABLE in line 4. Line 4 is the same line 4 as in the picture. I checked. Can anyone help with that problem?