# Flash/Php/MySQL Registration Form

Tags: php, mysql, flash, registration

I've been to almost every forum possible with this question (including this one). I almost got the answer to my question. The problem is no one seems to figure out my problem because everything looks right, and everything looks right to me too. Can someone please help me? Here are my codes.

Flash Code:

```
var lvSend:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var lvReceive:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

register_button.onRelease = function(){
var valid:Boolean = validateForm();
if (valid) {
    //gather information and put in loadvars object
    lvSend.username = username1.text;
    lvSend.password = password1.text;
    lvSend.email = email1.text;
    lvSend.sendAndLoad("register.php", lvReceive, "POST");
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
};
lvReceive.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
if (success) {
    username1.text = "";
    password1.text = "";
    email1.text = "";
}
}
function validateForm():Boolean {
if (username1.text == "" || password1.text == "" || email1.text == "") {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Php Code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXPWb.png
(Sorry its in link form)

Please favorite this or something until I get an answer because I've been everywhere and no one could help me. :/ BTW I have been getting a few blank entries into my database but I don't know why. Also, the lvReceive function doesn't seem to work, but when I add the username1.text = ""; into the register_button function it seems to clear the text fields. Please help me. I left the database info on the php file cause I thought maybe the database I entered could be the problem, but I did use this php code with an html file and it worked fine. I will accept any answers. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: What is the problem? If the problem is specifically related to your database having blank entries, then edit your post to only include code related to writing to the database.

Comment: In the future, you can use sites like http://pastebin.com/ to post code snippets that might be too long to include in a question.

Comment: Sorry. I was looking for a site like that but I wasn't sure what to google to find that type of sote. :/ Thanks

Comment: My problem is that I am having problems connecting to the database in order for the information to be sent. I am not sure whats causing the problem, but I just mentioned that I'm getting blank forms so if you guys only see a problem in the forms being sent blank then you could help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash Registration Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217074/flash-registration-form)

Answer (score 0):

```
lvSend.sendAndLoad("register.php", lvReceive, "POST");
```

You put the information in lvSend and not in lvReceive.
Perhaps you should put the information in lvReceive:

```
    lvReceive.username = username1.text;
    lvReceive.password = password1.text;
    lvReceive.email = email1.text;
    lvSend.sendAndLoad("register.php", lvReceive, "POST");
```